# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier not returning correct prototype cell sometimes

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

I've got a tableView defined in my storyboard layout, with two dynamic prototypes defined inside it, one for portrait and one for landscape.

Most of the time the table renders fine, but sometimes when I rotate the device, and afterward call [tableView reloadData], the tableViewCell is coming back as a generic cell, instead of my custom one.

I notice it, because the cell is a standard cell with 320 width, 44 height; instead of my custom width and height.  It has no subviews defined, but when displayed on the screen has my unconfigured subviews in it.

I was able to bypass it somewhat by moving a reloadData around to viewDidLoad, but mainly it happens after I rotate the device now.

I tried doing [tableView reloadData] after a 1 second delay after the rotation, and sometimes several come back generic, sometimes they are all good.

It seems to be cells that weren't visible previously also.  Like if landscape mode shows 12 of 15 cells, when rotating to Portrait 12 cells are great but the last 3 cells come back as generic duds after I reload the data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = @"";
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
       [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        identifier = @"tableViewCellPortrait";
    } else {
        identifier = @"tableViewCellLandscape";
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    // cell is never nil, but dequeue above sometimes returns a "generic" empty cell instead of the one of the identifier...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSDictionary *data = _tableLayoutData[indexPath.row];

    // when the "generic" cell loads, all these labels come back as "nil"
    // the generic cell has no subviews, is empty
    UILabel *circleIcon = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *primaryPayerLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *partySizeLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:4];

    // since nil, this can't be set here, and comes back as the value in the prototype once rendered
    primaryPayerLabel.text = data[@"name"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Did you see both landscape and portrait cells rendered? Generic cell could be visible only if you mispelled in interface builder or in code your identifier, but in such cases either portrait or landscape cells will be not visible at all.

Comment: Portrait and landscape are being rendered most of the time, correctly.  In all cases dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier does come back with something, it is never nil.  Sometimes it isn't intialized in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  And then when it renders it is correct, but entirely unconfigured.   It's like there is a delay to load it, and by the time it does it is too late to edit it.

Comment: You need to debug the logic; there's not enough code here to help and it relies on orientation changes which we can't emulate by looking at code. Where is the code to reload the table view on orientation change? Is this always called correctly (add `NSLog`s)?  Also, add  `NSLog`s next to the setting of the `identifier` to make sure that the correct one is selected by comparing with the `NSLog` next to the table view reload. Finally, as you are using `orientation` make sure you use `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` and a matched `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`.

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664890/reloaddata-in-a-uitableview-when-deviceorientation-change looks like you have race cindition in calls of orientation changes and cellForRow, as result cells loaded not consistently.

Comment: Also note that this design breaks with iPad and iOS 9 with multiple apps on screen. The iPad can be landscape but the app could be displaying as if portrait. You need to move to size classes to fix this problem.

Comment: I believe size classes don't differentiate between ipad portrait/landscape unforunately.  but very good point.

Comment: What do the NSLog's I suggested say? Is this a race condition? And where are your calls to `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` and the matched `endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` as per the documentation 2nd paragraph (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/)?

Comment: I added beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications in the viewDidLoad, but it didn't help.  orientations were being returned correctly either way.

Comment: One thing I notice is that if I reload the table correctly before rotating, and then stop reloading it on the rotation call, then it works fine.  rotating it seems to automatically reload it on its own somehow, since the prototypes switch.  This could be the race condition.

Comment: I've had this happen again on a different view.  I've found that after I retrieve my data I have to call reloadData twice.  Once immediately then again after about .15 seconds, and the second time always loads.  This seems very odd.